# Build Iphone app that can recognise colour from streaming camera

Tags: iphone, xcode, camera

I am building an iphone app to recognise a specific colour through the iphone camera when placed onto a colour board.

Note that I want it to work through the streaming camera output not just a still image or photo.

My initial thoughts were to scan series of pixels (say 4 on each corner of the camera feed) and if the colours registered in each pixel match, then display colour (in text) to user.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as far as example code or API or even if there is a better design solution to the problem.